# Json LD - Breadcrumbs - Logic for 3 or more path-levels in url

Tags: javascript, json-ld

i have this component for add Json LD schema to my pages.
Works great for urls like `mysite.com/page` or `mysite.com/page/subpage`... but, if i access to `mysite.com/page/subpage/another-page`, last schema thing is wrong : says `mysite.com/subpage/another-page` instead `mysite.com/page/subpage/another-page`

I know that problem is here  `` const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : `${baseURL}/${segments[index - 1]}/${segment}`; `` but i don't know how to make it works for segments higer than 2 levels. Could somebody help me please?

```
// Scripts
import { capitalizeEachWord } from "@/src/utils/utils";
import { scriptBodyUnencoded } from "@/src/components/functions/scriptFunctions";

const SCRIPT_BODY = dynamicSlug => {
  const slug = dynamicSlug.substring(1);
  const segments = slug.split("/");

  const baseURL = `${process.env.CW_BASE_URL}`;

  return `
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "item": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "@id":  "${baseURL}",
            "name": "Home",
            "image": ""
          }
        },    
        ${segments.map((segment, index) => {
    const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : `${baseURL}/${segments[index - 1]}/${segment}`;
    return `
          {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": ${index + 2},
              "item": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "@id": "${url}",
                "name": "${capitalizeEachWord(segment.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " "))}",
                "image": ""
              }}`;
  })}
      ]
    }
  `;
};

const JsonLdDynamicBreadcrumbComponent = ({
  dynamicSlug,
}) => {
  try {
    return (
      <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: scriptBodyUnencoded(SCRIPT_BODY(dynamicSlug)),
        }}
        id="JsonLdDynamicBreadcrumbComponent"
        type="application/ld+json"
      />
    );
  } catch (error) {
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment -- need to return empty fragment*/ }
    return <></>;
  }
};

export default JsonLdDynamicBreadcrumbComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

while iterating, try joining all segments until the current by its index:

try:

```
${segments.map((segment, index) => {
    const url = `${baseURL}/${segments.slice(0, index+1).join('/')}`;
    //..
```